# Primefaces selectManyMenu: Showing selected items on top of list

Tags: user-interface, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces' selectManyMenu to display a list of hundreds of items. I've also included a filter on top. The issue is that when I select, say, the 200th item in the list, I have to manually scroll down to the 200th item each time to see if it has been checked.

I want it so that whenever I select an item, it moves to the top of the menu, so that it is easy to view all the selected items from that list at the top without having to scroll down and up all the time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd try to use query to manipulate the dom. Both the visible part and all the real option elements

Comment: Query should be jquery

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your component is getting updated when selecting or unselecting an item, and that's the reason you're reloading the list and losing your scroll position.

Else, it looks like you could use a workround for this. Something like

1. Catch the select/unselect/change event and trigger a backing Bean function where
2. You rearrange you list of items sot that the selected ones will be pushed first
3. `oncomplete`, you will update your selectManyMenu component.

By the way, maybe it's time to think again if you're using the right component and UX practice. and I have the impression that `selectManyMenu` is not meant to be used with lists of 200+ items. Personally I think you should avoid using a list that will have to scroll down, for selectMany components. For example you could use another component like a [pickList](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml)

Comment: I agree, it's not the most elegant of approaches to the problem but it's a UI that's been designed by the higher up's, and they're well aware of the problems associated with it, and are still choosing to go forward with it. My job is to implement, not question. I've thought of putting a separate box on top of each list that shows just the selected items. It seems marginally less convoluted than sorting the list each time a selection/deselection is done. Thanks!